# Set property on Node based on relationship property

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I am making a query and I need the result of that query to affect the properties of another node.

```
return client.Cypher
            .Match("(person:Person),(me:Person)")
            .Where((Person person) => person.Email == friend)
            .AndWhere((Person me) => me.Email == username)

             //is friend, doesn't matter about relationship direction
            .OptionalMatch("(me)-[t:IS_FRIENDS_WITH{confirmed:true}]-(person)")
            .Set("person.isFriend = 'isfriend'")
            .With("person,me,t")

             //pending, I added them, we are waiting for them
            .OptionalMatch("(me)-[u:IS_FRIENDS_WITH{confirmed:false}]->(person)")
            .Set("person.isFriend = 'pending'")
            .With("person,me,t,u")


             //awaiting response, they added me, I need to respond
            .OptionalMatch("(me)<-[v:IS_FRIENDS_WITH{confirmed:false}]-(person)")
            .Set("person.isFriend = 'response'")
            .With("person,me,t,u,v")
```

Now, as this currently runs I get 'response' as the result every single time, which makes sense with the way I wrote the query, but obviously this is not the solution I need.
Can anyone help me set the 'person.IsFriend' variable correctly based on if the person is a friend, if we are waiting for them to respond, or if they are waiting for us to respond. Kind of like an If/Else statement, but for the client.

I want to return a Person object (called friend) that has the property isFriend set according to the rules in the query, so a string of either 'friend', 'pending' or 'response'
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to return? When you say you get 'response' every time, do you mean all the `.isFriend` properties are set to `response` or just that you get it back? Do you use `t` later on in the query? Could you put the `.Return` statement up? Ta!

Comment: I get the response of person.isFriend = 'response' for the single user node that is returned (friend). Event if the relationship [IS_FRENDS_WITH{confirmed=true}] which should return person.isFriend = 'friend'

Comment: @ChrisSkardon t is used for updating the lastviewed property of the relationship, it's kind of a weight for the friendship. the return is: .Return((me, person) => new ProfileObject { Person = person.As<Person>(), Me = me.As<Person>() }).Results.ToList(); That's kind of it.

Comment: Does the Cypher work in the web page? i.e. if you directly run it in the browser?

Comment: No, but it's quite obvious why, and the solution below shows something I did not know you could do, using CASE/WHEN? Wow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, Have spoken to higher powers and have this as a solution:

```
var query = gc.Cypher.Match("(person:Person),(me:Person)")
    .Where((Person person) => person.Email == potentialFriend)
    .AndWhere((Person me) => me.Email == username)
    .Set( @"person.isFriend = CASE 
            WHEN(me) -[:IS_FRIENDS_WITH { confirmed: true}]-(person)THEN 'isFriend'
            WHEN(me) -[:IS_FRIENDS_WITH { confirmed: false}]->(person)THEN 'pending'
            WHEN(me) < -[:IS_FRIENDS_WITH { confirmed: false}]-(person)THEN 'response'
            END")
    .Return(person => person.As<Person>());
```

Comment: didn't know I could use CASE/SWITCH, this is amazing, thank you, tested and working.